# How to do operations with columns based on date and column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas Dataframe:

[image: Dataframe i have]

My goal is to perform some additions and subtractions based on column value conditions, and store the results inside a new column `pl`.

This is the Dataframe I want to have:

[image: df desidered]

The first non-NaN value will be necessarily in the `entry` column.

First scenario:

I want that, if the next non-NaN value (after a non-NaN inside "entry" and then a non-NaN inside "tp1") is contained inside "tp2" column, then do this operation: (tp1 - entry) + (tp2 - entry)

Second scenario:

I want that, if the next non-NaN value (after entry) is contained inside the column "sl1" then do this operation: sl1 - entry.

Third scenario:

I want that, if the next non-NaN value (after entry) is contained inside the column "tp1" and there's a non-NaN value inside the column "sl2" then do this operation: tp1 - entry.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

tbl = {"date" :["2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", 
                    "2022-02-28", "2022-02-28","2022-02-28", "2022-02-28", "2022-02-01", 
                   "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01"],
       "entry" : ["NaN", "NaN", 1.2, "NaN", "NaN","NaN", 1.3, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.2, "NaN", 
                  "NaN",],
       "tp1" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.4, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
                1.3, "NaN"],
       "sl1" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.15, "NaN", "NaN", 
                "NaN", "NaN"],
       "tp2" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.5, "NaN","NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
                "NaN", "NaN"],
       "sl2" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN","NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
               "NaN", 1.2]}


df = pd.DataFrame(tbl)

df = df.replace('NaN', float('nan'))

############## This is the way i'm trying to achive what i want:#########

#this code will only make tp1 - entry, or sl1 - entry, but it's wrong 
#because it's made based on a dataframe without "sl2,tp2" consideration

group = df['date'] 

s1 = df['tp1'].fillna(df['sl1']).groupby(group).bfill()
s2 = df['entry'].groupby(group).bfill()

df.loc[~group.duplicated(), 'pl'] = s1-s2
```

I'm blocked here, I don't understand how to code the other conditions, Any ideas?

**Edit** The first value inside pl column is wrong, it should be 0.5. Not 0.20

Comment: i couldn’t understand the logic…

Comment: is the entry column always has value first?, what happen if there is another value in entry for example?

Comment: @adirabargil Thanks for the comment. Could you be more specific? My intention is to do operations based on column's values conditions. For esample: if we have a first non-NaN value inside the "entry" column and the next First column value is inside "sl1" column so perform this operation: sl1-entry and store it inside "pl" new column. The last lines of my code explain a little my intentions, it's working code, but I code it not considering "sl2" and "tp2" columns.

Comment: I don't need the next values only the First one, so ignore the next values OF THE SAME DAY

Comment: when you say "next" by what order? column wize or row wize order?

Comment: Let's consider the "entry" column, this column could have rows like this: NaN, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, NaN. This happens even for the other columns.

Comment: so in that case what would be the subtraction ? what if after the first 1.2 enrty, in the tp1 column there is a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take advatage of numpy `ravel()` function to flatten the df without the date column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tbl = {"date" :["2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", 
                    "2022-02-28", "2022-02-28","2022-02-28", "2022-02-28", "2022-02-01", 
                   "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01"],
       "entry" : ["NaN", "NaN", 1.2, "NaN", "NaN","NaN", 1.3, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.2, "NaN", 
                  "NaN",],
       "tp1" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.4, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
                1.3, "NaN"],
       "sl1" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.15, "NaN", "NaN", 
                "NaN", "NaN"],
       "tp2" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 1.5, "NaN","NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
                "NaN", "NaN"],
       "sl2" : ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN","NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
               "NaN", 1.2]}


df = pd.DataFrame(tbl)

df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
def transform(x):
    arr = np.empty(x.shape[0])
    arr[:] = np.nan
    flatten = x.iloc[:, 1:6].values.ravel()
    flatten = flatten[~np.isnan(flatten)][:2]
    arr[0] = np.diff(flatten)[0]
    return pd.DataFrame({"p": arr}, index=x.index)


p = df.groupby("date").apply(transform) 
df['p'] = p
df
```

the resulting dataframe are:

```
    date    entry   tp1 sl1 tp2 sl2 p
0   2022-02-27  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.20
1   2022-02-27  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   2022-02-27  1.2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   2022-02-27  NaN 1.4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   2022-02-27  NaN NaN NaN 1.5 NaN NaN
5   2022-02-28  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -0.15
6   2022-02-28  1.3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   2022-02-28  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   2022-02-28  NaN NaN 1.15NaN NaN NaN
9   2022-02-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.10
10  2022-02-01  1.2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
11  2022-02-01  NaN 1.3 NaN NaN NaN NaN
12  2022-02-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.2 NaN
```

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for your detailed answer, Considering the 2022-02-27 date, The first value inside pl column  is wrong, it should be 0.5, not 0.2 as the photo says, I figured out this and made an edit after I posted the question. My error.

Comment: let me check it out

Comment: The formula is: (tp1-entry) + (tp2- entry)

Comment: take a look now

Comment: btw the first secenario doesnt match the pattetn you wrote...